# Let $f$ be analytic function on a disk |z|$\le1 $ with |$f(z)$|$\le$M on |z|=1 and $f(a)=0$ where a is a complex number with |a|<1.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be  analytic function on a disk |z|$\le1 $ with |$f(z)$|$\le$M on |z|=1 and $f(a)=0$ where a is a complex number with |a|<1.

> Show that |$f(z)$|$\le$($M/|1-\bar az|)*$|z-a| for all z in |z|$\le$$1.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\varphi (z) =-\frac{z-a}{1-\overline{a} z}$ then $g(z) =\frac{1}{M} (f\circ \varphi )(z) $ satisfies the assumptions of Schwarz Lemma hence $$\left|\frac{1}{M} (f\circ \varphi )(z)\right|\leq |z|$$ and therefore $$|f(z)|\leq M|\varphi^{-1} (z) |$$ hence $$ |f(z)|\leq M\left|-\frac{z-a}{1-\overline{a} z}\right|$$